# Linq-OrderByDescending doesn't work for me-ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to order my list by **idEtatD** but this attribute isn't my table primarykey or id it's a normal attribute migrated from another table,nut **OrderBy** or **OrderByDescending** didn't give me a result my list still not  ordered by **idEtatD**.

```
 public ActionResult ListeDemande( int? page)
        {


            traçabilitérepository=new TraçabilitéDemandeRepository(db);

            var listdemandes = (from d in db.Demande_Gabarit
                                join t in db.Traçabilité_Demande_Gabarit
                                    on d.id_demande equals t.iddemande into ThisList
                                from t in ThisList.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                select new
                                {
                                    id_demande=d.id_demande,
                                    NumDemande = d.NumDemande,
                                    Emetteur = d.Emetteur,
                                    Date = d.Date,
                                    Ligne = d.Ligne.designation,
                                    Etat = t.Etat_Demande_Gabarit.EtatDemande

                                }).ToList().Select(x => new DemandeViewModel()
                                {
                                    NumDemande = x.NumDemande,
                                    Emetteur = x.Emetteur,
                                    Date = x.Date,
                                    designation = x.Ligne,
                                    EtatDemande = x.Etat,
                                    id_demande = x.id_demande
                                });
            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(listdemandes.OrderByDescending(x => x.idEtatD).ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

Please I need your help and thank you.

Comment: If the above code compiles, then your `emandeViewModel` has a property `idEtatD` which isn't set, so most likely it contains one and the same (default) value, so it's normal `OrderBy(Descending)` to not sort the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order the items at the beginning, but you need to include it in the list:

```
traçabilitérepository = new TraçabilitéDemandeRepository(db);

            var listdemandes = (from d in db.Demande_Gabarit
                                join t in db.Traçabilité_Demande_Gabarit
                                    on d.id_demande equals t.iddemande into ThisList
                                from t in ThisList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                orderby t.idEtatD descending

                                select new
                                {
                                    id_demande = d.id_demande,
                                    NumDemande = d.NumDemande,
                                    Emetteur = d.Emetteur,
                                    Date = d.Date,
                                    Ligne = d.Ligne.designation,
                                    Etat = t.Etat_Demande_Gabarit.EtatDemande,
                                    idEtatD = XXXX
                                }).ToList().Select(x => new DemandeViewModel()
                                {
                                    NumDemande = x.NumDemande,
                                    Emetteur = x.Emetteur,
                                    Date = x.Date,
                                    designation = x.Ligne,
                                    EtatDemande = x.Etat,
                                    id_demande = x.id_demande
                                });
```